# Dealing with logic gates, how do I build a circuit from k-map equations?

Tags: circuit, flip-flop

My partner walked off with the sheet so I can't provide you with the table but I have the 6 supposed equations. I need to build a 3-bit up-counter with JK flip-flops. Following are the equations:

```
J(Q1) = ~Q1 * Q0
K(Q1) = Q1 * Q0
J(Q2) = Q2 * Q0
K(Q2) = Q1 * Q0
J(Q0) = ~Q0
K(Q0) = Q0
```

I'm at a loss of how to even begin constructing this circuit. Any guidance would be appreciated. I'm using Logisim to construct the circuit. In theory these equations are all I should need to construct this circuit... which is why I'm asking this question here.

Comment: You should consider asking this on the Electrical Engineering StackExchange community.

Answer (score 0):

in Logisim it's easy,

Goto Window->Combinational Analysis

Then choose the Expressions tab.

Enter your equations one per line (Or use the other tools (Truth Tables/Maps)

Make sure you have your inputs and outputs set up before you start entering equations.

Then click on Build circuit and follow the instructions.